# Getting "0" (invalid data ) from Sqlite command

Tags: c#, sqlite

I am trying to fetch a column a from table, but it gets 0 value and column contains a value which is (2).
here is my code

```
obj.GetCon().Open();
            obj.cmd = new SQLiteCommand("SELECT Payable FROM VendorLedgers WHERE VendorId=" + Convert.ToInt32( payBill.VendorId), obj.con);
            obj.read = obj.cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (obj.read.Read())
            {
                MessageBox.Show(obj.read.GetValue(0).ToString());
                dues = obj.read["Payable"].ToString();
                string[] split_due = dues.Split('(', ')');
                int dueamount1 = Convert.ToInt32(split_due[1]); //and it prints here index was outside the bound error
                dueamount.Add(dueamount1);
            }
            obj.GetCon().Close();
```

and here is my query output on database

[image]

please help if anyone know how to fix it

Comment: `string[] split_due = dues.Split('(', ')');` … how do you know this split was successful and has a size of 2 or more?

Comment: this will work after when i get the data in dues variable, my data in database is (2) so i want 2 from it that's why i split it .

Comment: I believe you should read some docs before proceeding. E.g. this one may be helpful: https://zetcode.com/csharp/sqlite/ Examples are using C# 8, but it should be easy for you to convert it to < C# 8. BR

Answer (score 0):

I have not worked for SQLite. But with `while(obj.read.Read())` you read one row at a time.

Then access the corresponding column with `obj.read["Payable"]`.

**So what do you need split!**

```
while (obj.read.Read())
{
    MessageBox.Show(obj.read.GetInt32(0).ToString());
    int dueamount1 = obj.read.GetInt32(0);
    dueamount.Add(dueamount1);
}
```

Comment: this will work after when i get the data in dues variable, my data in database is (2) so i want 2 from it that's why i split it

Comment: and i getting 0 output in messagebox, so it means it is not fetching the record

Comment: use obj.read.GetInt32(0) . i edited the answer . test now